# Using 2D vector in C++ class returns error "Expression must have pointer-to-object type". What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector

Dear Stack Overflow community,

As this is my first question as both a new Stack Overflow member and relatively new programmer, I hope this question doesn't come off as stupid. I am trying to make a grid-building class whose purpose is to draw and update a 2D console-based grid. The main problem I encountered was how to set up the grid dimensions. I've searched online through youtube videos, documentation/tutorial sites, and Stack Overflow and thought I saw my answer in the use of multidimensional vectors, as they have the flexibility in size that arrays don't. I want to make a 2D vector of my class called Space, which holds any type of variable value, almost like a blank Object. But when I got to the cpp file and defined a function to print the grid I got the error "Error: expression must have a pointer-to-object type". What does this mean? I've search my resources and only found things relating to pointers(which is a topic I'm currently trying to learn, but its relevance to this goes way over my head) and basic syntax errors. Here's the code in the cpp file:

```
void Grid::Draw()
{
  std::cout << "\n    a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z\n-------------------------------------------------- - \n";


  //First Row Output
  std::cout << "    ";

  for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
  {
      std::cout << char(i + 65) << " ";
  }

  std::cout << "\n";
  std::cout << "    ";

  for (int i = 1; i < width; i++)
  {
      std::cout << "--";
  }

  std::cout << "-" << "\n";


  //Each proceeding row

  for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
  {

      std::cout << i << "| ";

      for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
      {
          std::cout << Grid::gridSpace[i][j];
          if (j = width - 1)
            std::cout << "\n";
      }
  }

}
```

And the header file:

```
...    
private:

    int height, width;

    typedef std::vector<Space> Row;
    typedef std::vector<Row> SpaceGrid;
    SpaceGrid gridSpace (Row(height), Row(width) ) ;
...
```

Thank you and sorry if the formatting is funky! I'm still new to this.

Comment: `gridSpace` seems to be a function and you are trying to access with `gridSpace[][]`

Comment: I assume you want to declare `gridSpace` with `SpaceGrid gridSpace;` and define it's size in `Grid`'s constructor.

Comment: But I also want the size of the vector to change dynamically at runtime. Should I just give it defaults and use the resize function?

Comment: @Ra1nWarden And I thought `gridSpace` was my vector of vectors of my class "Space"? Unless I declared it as a function.

Comment: @CharlieNaya Not sure what you mean, the only place I see a `gridSpace` in the code you quoted was the function name.

Comment: @CharlieNaya using default size + resize could work. And the syntax you used declares `gridSpace` as a function, instead of a vector of vectors.

Comment: Oh, thanks so much guys! I forgot such a simple thing. Code seems to be working now :)